# Include images in ASP.NET Core App with React

Tags: asp.net, reactjs

I have a react app running on ASP.NET Core server.

I'm trying to show image on one of my react pages.
(image is located in: "project_folder/ClientApp/src/images/progress_bar.gif")

But neither of this works:

```
<img alt="loading..." src={'./progress_bar.gif'} />
<img alt="loading..." src={'images/progress_bar.gif'} />
<img alt="loading..." src={'./images/progress_bar.gif'} />
<img alt="loading..." src={'require(./images/progress_bar.gif')} />
```

I even tried to disable this:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Still no luck. But i can load files thru css no problems like:

```
background-image: url("./images/login-left.jpg");
```

this produces smth like: `https://localhost:44329/static/media/login-left.270403e0.jpg`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below options. These are the two ways to import images in react. The reason require isn’t working for you because you have added require in quotes so it’s a string you shouldn’t use quotes. Make sure your path is correct. If your path is correct then below options would work

```
 import progressBar from '../images/progress_bar.gif';

   <img alt="loading..." src={progressBar} />
```

Or

```
  <img alt="loading..." src={require('../images/progress_bar.gif')} />
```

Comment: Module not found: Can't resolve './images/progress_bar.gif' in '...\ClientApp\src\components'

Comment: You need to specify right path. Check your path. Your path is incorrect and that’s why you get that error

Comment: I was missing another dot all the time, correct path was '../images/progress_bar.gif'

Comment: Cool. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

With Webpack, using static assets like images and fonts works similarly to CSS.

You can **`import` a file right in a TypeScript module**. This tells Webpack to include that file in the bundle. Unlike CSS imports, importing a file gives you a string value. This value is the final path you can reference in your code.

To reduce the number of requests to the server, importing images that are less than 10,000 bytes returns a [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) instead of a path. This applies to the following file extensions: bmp, gif, jpg, jpeg, and png. SVG files are excluded due to [#1153](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1153).

Before getting started, you must define each type of asset as a valid module format. Otherwise, the TypeScript compiler will generate an error like this:

> Cannot find module './logo.png'.

To import asset files in TypeScript, create a new type definition file in your project, and name it something like *assets.d.ts*. Then, add a line for each type of asset that you need to import:

```
declare module "*.gif";
declare module "*.jpg";
declare module "*.jpeg";
declare module "*.png";
declare module "*.svg";
```

In this case, we've added several image file extensions as valid module formats. Now that the compiler is configured, here is an example of importing an image file:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg'; // Tell Webpack this JS file uses this image

console.log(logo); // /logo.84287d09.png

function Header() {
  // Import result is the URL of your image
  return <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />;
}

export default Header;
```

**A complete Refrence** for [Adding Images, Fonts, and Files](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/react-spa#adding-images-fonts-and-files).